# Relationship between L and PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I have a question have to answer, so that, if anyone have the answer, please help me.

The problem is: Give a self-contained proof that $\mathsf{L} \neq \mathsf{PSPACE}$
where:

$\qquad \mathsf{L}      = \{ L \mid L \text{ is a language decidable in logarithmic space} \}$ and

$\qquad  \mathsf{PSPACE} = \{ L \mid L \text{ is a language decidable in polynomial space}\}$.

Comment: Just take e.g. $f(n)=n^2$ and follow the proof of the space hierarchy theorem.

Comment: This question does not show any effort on your part. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You might start with wikipedia: [Space hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem#Proof).